# Chrome animation inspector removing animation? How do I record animation?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, frontend, css-animations

This is a simple question.  I want to record the animation of three blue circles on this website, "https://www.cassie.net/" underneath the words We get it...  However, in chromes animation inspector it shows the animation for 1 second than disappears.  How do I get the animation from the inspector?

Comment: I can't replicate. Try "Restore defaults and reload" in the settings of the developer's tool.

Comment: that doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm Likhon,

you can use [techsmith video-editor](https://www.techsmith.com/video-editor.html), recorded then edit video

Comment: I'm talking about the chrome-inspector animation tool for CSS